# How to assign session variable directly from html tag?

Tags: php, html, session-variables

I am trying to set $_SESSION variable directly into  tag but it doesn't work.

Below is my tag

```
<td><a href="persons.php?name='.$row['name'].'"> '.$row['name'].'</a></td>
```

Can I do something like

```
<td><a href="persons.php?name= $_SESSION['test'] ='.$row['name'].'"> '.$row['name'].'</a></td>
```

I have also tried doing

```
        <?php
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['name'] = ".$row['name'].";
```

and then passing the $_SESSION['name'] into  tag but I am doing it wrong.

```
        <?php
        session_start();
        if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) == 0){
            echo '<tr><td colspan="8">Data not found.</td></tr>';
        }else{
            $no = 1;
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
                echo '
                <tr>
                    <td>'.$no.'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['emp_id'].'</td>
                    <td><a href="test.php?name='.$row['name'].'"> '.$row['name'].'</a></td>
                    <td>'.$row['emp_address'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['emp_dob'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['emp_phone'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['emp_dept'].'</td>
                    <td>';
                echo '

                $no++;
            }
        }
        ?>
```

Basically I am tying to store value of .$row['name']. to $_SESSION variable and then pass it into  tag.

Comment: I suggest reading [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question). Also, be sure to take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: `<td><a href="persons.php?name=<?=$row['name'];?>"><?=$row['name'];?></a></td>` -- in HTML, you can echo PHP variables by wrapping it in `<?=` and `;?>` OR `<? echo` `;?>`

Answer (score 0):

Every bit of PHP code must be surrounded by `<?php` and `?>`. If you only echo a viariable (like in your case), you can use `<?=` instead (it means the same as `<?php echo`.

```
<?php
        session_start();
        if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) == 0) { ?>
            <tr><td colspan="8">Data not found.</td></tr>
        <?php } else {
            $no = 1;
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){ ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?= $no ?></td>
                    <td><?= $row['emp_id'] ?></td>
                    <td><a href="test.php?name=<?= $row['name'] ?>"> <?= $row['name'] ?></a></td>
                    <td><?= $row['emp_address'] ?></td>
                    <td><?= $row['emp_dob'] ?></td>
                    <td><?= $row['emp_phone'] ?></td>
                    <td><?= $row['emp_dept'] ?></td>
                    <td>

                <?php
                $no++;
            }
        }
        ?>
```

EDIT

The problem is that you are trying to both assign and output a var at the same time, which is a bad practice and should not be done. First you assign the variable and then you echo it. So:

```
<?php
    $_SESSION['test'] = $row['name'];
?>

<td><a href="persons.php?name='<?= $_SESSION['test'] ?>'"> <?= $_SESSION['test'] ?></a></td>
```

Comment: sorry I didn't pasted the entire code, my tag is already surrounded by <?php and ?>.  I just want  to know can I specify session variable directly in to that <td> tag line as mentioned above?

Comment: You should not surround the html wit `<?php ?>', just the variable, as I showed in my answer. This should work.

Comment: @ Michał Skrzypek getting

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in /var

Comment: Did you remove the outer `<?php` ? Also, which PHP do you use?

Comment: @ Michał Skrzypek I can't doing doing that will break my fetching code, please see the edited code.

Comment: You can jump in and out of php as often as you like. Also, when you have a lot of HTML it is much easier to read than long echos. Check out the edited answer.

Comment: Make sense, but how  do I set session variable value that's the main issue? can I do 

<?= $_SESSION["test"] = $row['name']; ?>


or 



$_SESSION["test"] = <?= $row['name'] ?>



or 
or can I directly specify it into 

<td><a href="projects.php?hostname=<? = $row['hostname'] ?>"> <?= $row['hostname'] ?></a></td>
?

Comment: `<?= $_SESSION["test"] = $row['name']; ?>` won't work, because `<?=` is an equivalent of `<?php echo`. You do not want to echo, so use `<?php $_SESSION["test"] = $row['name']; ?>` assuming you have got all the code for starting session and using while before that. Generally you can jump in and out, but blocks of php can be longer than one line. Start with `<?php`, write all the logic (starting session, assigning variables), then close it with `?>` and then use `<?=` only where you need to echo something.